# Increment for loop by variable

Tags: c++, for-loop, increment

I am taking in sound as a float called scaledVol. I wish to change the spacing of the letters being drawn out by scaledVol.

This is the code snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < camWidth; i+=7){
    for (int j = 0; j < camHeight; j+=9){
        // get the pixel and its lightness (lightness is the average of its RGB values)
        float lightness = pixelsRef.getColor(i,j).getLightness();
        // calculate the index of the character from our asciiCharacters array
        int character = powf( ofMap(lightness, 0, 255, 0, 1), 2.5) * asciiCharacters.size();
        // draw the character at the correct location
        ofSetColor(0, 255, 0);
        font.drawString(ofToString(asciiCharacters[character]), f, f);
    }
}
```

where i sets the width between character spacing and j sets the height between character spacing.

Instead of incrementing by 7 or 9, I would like to increment by a float called scaledVol.

Comment: "Instead of incrementing by 7 or 9, I would like to increment by a float called scaledVol" have you tried replacing the 7 or 9 with a float called scaledVol?

Comment: I have tried to replace the 7 or 9 with scaledVol and whilst xcode compiles the project, it does not run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Instead of incrementing by 7 or 9, I would like to increment by a float called scaledVol.

Then code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < camWidth; i+=(int)scaledVol){
```

You may want to take the floor of, and ensure the conversion is done once, the increment; perhaps code instead

```
 int incr = (int) floor(scaledVol);
 assert (incr > 0);
 for (int i = 0; i < camWidth; i+=incr) {
```

Read more about [floor(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/floor.3.html), [ceil(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ceil.3.html), [round(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/round.3.html), and [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) and [rounding errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding_error)

Please use your debugger (e.g. `gdb`) to understand more.

You could use more C++ friendly [casts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) e.g.

```
 int incr = int(floor(scaledVol));
```

or [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)

```
 int incr = static_cast<int>(floor(scaledVol));
```

or perhaps even [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

```
 int incr = reinterpret_cast<int>(floor(scaledVol));
```

<sup>which might not work as you want, particularily if both numerical types have same size.</sup>

Comment: Hope that `incr != 0`

Comment: You have the potential for rounding errors (hence looping too often)

Comment: I attempted this and it compiles except the debug application does not respond. Unfortunately, I'm not seeing any errors.

Comment: c-style-casts are a bad idea. use `int(scaledVol)` instead of `(int)scaledVol`.

Comment: Thanks, managed to use this and get it working. Had to map my variable first but then your technique of the c++ friendly cast solved my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Need something like

```
for (float i = 0.0f; i < camWidth; i+=scaleVol){
```

Assuming that `camWidth` is a float. If not cast it to a float.

This will also over come a problem with rounding errors when converting `scaledVol` to an int

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float` as the type of the two loop variables, and then cast them to `int`:

```
for (float x = 0; (int)x < camWidth; x+=scaledVol) {
  int i = (int)x;
  for (float y = 0; (int)y < camHeight; y+=scaledVol) {
    int j = (int)y;
    // the rest of the code using i and j
  }
}
```

Be careful that `scaledVol` has best be greater than 1, otherwise you will have consecutive values of `i` and `j` that are equal. Your treatment in `// the rest of the code`` may not like that.